# Restrict React-Router for a specific path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have got a github page. I have so many live project demos on github pages. Now I wanted to upload my personal portfolio to my root github project directory. (ex: https://username.github.io/) Now I have made my personal portfolio using basically react and react-router. Everything was working fine. But at some point I figured out that the other projects which is living in other routes (ex: https://username.github.io/someOtherRepo), react-router is also catching them and it was basically showing me a not found page from my portfolio(root). So is it possible to tell react-router that it should work for some specific routes only? I don't want it to catch everything after '/' I want to keep my portfolio with react-router and I also want other projects to be shown on the github pages as usual. 
The link where I have uploaded the react application is here: https://zonayedpca.github.io
and I have some other projects on other repositories like this one: https://zonayedpca.github.io/ReactToDo
But see it doesn't load the original project. It loads only the first react application

Comment: did you try `exact` property?

Comment: I have used exact for my root route
```<Route exact path="/" component={Me} />```
But I haven't used for any other routes. Also I want to mention that I have made a route for not found paths as well... What should I do? Thanks for your reply

Comment: ```exact``` doesn't even work at all :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Actually `exact` works on this type of case. As I have uploaded my files to github and I have created the React app using create-react-app, theServiceWorker file was responsible for behaving in this way. After removing serviceworker, it is working as usual

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the following code:

```
<Route exact path="/" render{ () => <Redirect to="/Me" />
```